# iPhone use same TableView to drilldown multilevel for remote xml

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've to parse some XML files(Category-->Sub Category-->Sub Category-->Sub Category-->Details View) from web service and show in iphone TableView. Is there any way to use same table until the deatils View?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, but it's a lot more work than just pushing a new tableView each time. It will also be less apparent to the user what's going on if they are drilling down, but not pushing onto the nav stack.

I'm guessing by your profile that you're fairly new to iOS, so I'd suggest you get your app working in as straightforward a way as possible.  If you're trying to optimize by re-using the tableview, only do that after you know that it needs to be optimized.

You can write a class that handles any given level in your xml stack, and have a separate instance of that class for each level.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. Yes, I'm new in iPhone Development. And now I'm pushing a new table view each time. But I thought there must be some technique to reuse a table. Thanks

Comment: @Walid - as I said, there are techniques to re-use an instance of the table, but imo it's more work than it's worth (and probably not necessary as the SDK components are already pretty well optimized).  However, you should be able to re-use the table view controller class, at least for the 3 sub-category tables.